# How is ghc's code coverage implemented? Does it inhibit optimizations?

Tags: haskell, optimization, code-coverage, ghc

Does `-fhpc` inhibit optimizations or rewrite rules, in the same way that automatic cost centers do?

I'd also like a brief overview of how ghc implements code coverage, maybe with some pointers to source locations.

Comment: Might be worth checking out https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/hpc if you haven't seen it yet. It's a bit short, but it looks like it has some valuable info, and a paper.